# Amazon 500150 Error setting closing connection General SSLEngine

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-redshift

While connecting to **Amazon RedShift**, I getting the below error:

```
2016-04-14 13:49:30 ERROR SQL Exception when connecting [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: General SSLEngine problem.
java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: General SSLEngine problem.
    at workbench.db.DbDriver.connect(DbDriver.java:546)
    at workbench.db.ConnectionMgr.connect(ConnectionMgr.java:244)
    at workbench.db.ConnectionMgr.getConnection(ConnectionMgr.java:172)
    at workbench.gui.components.ConnectionSelector.doConnect(ConnectionSelector.java:227)
    at workbench.gui.components.ConnectionSelector$1.run(ConnectionSelector.java:131)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: General SSLEngine problem.
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.PGJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at workbench.db.DbDriver.connect(DbDriver.java:513)
    at workbench.db.ConnectionMgr.connect(ConnectionMgr.java:244)
    at workbench.db.ConnectionMgr.getConnection(ConnectionMgr.java:172)
    at workbench.gui.components.ConnectionSelector.doConnect(ConnectionSelector.java:227)
```

I am using SQL Workbench J to connect to the database system. The strangeness here it that the connection was working fine two days ago. This problem appeared from nowhere. Any idea??

We are following the exact steps written in the setup guide to add certificates to Java.

https://community.boomi.com/docs/DOC-2381

Am I missing anything here?

**UPDATE**

My Redshift database is SSL configured. We use SQL Workbench J (http://www.sql-workbench.net/) client to connect to that database. The issue now is that everytime we try to connect, we are getting the error I mentioned.

Below is our URL format:

```
jdbc:redshift://hostname:5439/dbname?ssl=true&sslmode=verify-full
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the Question details.

Answer (score 11):

It worked for me when I followed the solution given by cfregly on databricks forum. Please follow below URL for this solution:

https://forums.databricks.com/questions/867/ssl-connection-issues-with-redshift.html

Please try appending sslfactory value in the Connection URL string like below - it might work.

> ssl=true&**sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory**

Comment: This solution worked for me. I have some exact problem and when i added "&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
shareeditflag" i was able to connect to the Redshift DW

Comment: Note that this creates a potential security issue, since you (the client) are no longer validating the identity of the server.

Answer (score 4):

Please add the following without the server certificate

```
ssl=true&sslfactory=com.amazon.redshift.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

The following would be the possible values for sslfactory

```
com.amazon.redshift.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

Please see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-options.html

Comment: This solution works with Jetbrains IDE's datasource connections as well. Edit these values under 'Advanced' tab for Redshift driver in 'Datasources and Drivers' section in the IDE

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

Run the keystore keytool based on the Java install for the environment variable JAVA_HOME (you may have multiple java installs so just use the default). Use the default cacerts keystore that comes with the JRE which will have a password of "changeit". You need to download the [Redshift Certificate](https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/redshift-ssl-ca-cert.pem).

Then install the certificate for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin>keytool.exe -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -import -alias redshift -file redshift-ssl-ca-cert.pem
```

It will prompt you for the password ("changeit") and then should say the key has been added. If it fails its probably because you are not an admin user, so if in linux use sudo or in windows open the command window as administrator.

Start MYSQL Workbench using the cacerts keystore and the password entered above eg:

```
C:\apps\SQL-Workbench-Build118>java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -jar sqlworkbench.jar
```

You should be able to use the URL above and it should now work.